# stream analytics job with blob storage input not running continously

Tags: powerbi, azure-stream-analytics, azure-blob-storage

I created a stream analytics job which queries from input blob storage JSON, datastream, and output it to powerbi dataset, I found the job run for two times making two output event, and don't run again, I don't see continues running on the log of stream analytics, however I see that my blob storage keep modifying.

each time I want to modify my blob I just create a new blob with the same name, so it overwrites the old one with new data, and I see it keep changing, but it doesn't make output at powerbi, how frequently shall stream analytics run in my case , retrieving blob storage and make a new output

Stream Analytics resource id
/subscriptions/f80e5865-d8c1-4ac7-b102-ff72bdbe1188/resourceGroups/IotHub/providers/Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs/butterfly_streamanalytics

container url
https://butterflystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/butterflycontainer

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a new blob with a different name for new content. ASA doesn't look at a blob that it has already seen again.